# Find a posterior mean estimator

Tags: statistics

Assume $ X_1, X_2,... X_N$ are IID Gamma($r$ , $ \lambda$). Where r is constant. Find the posterior mean estimator of $\lambda$ for the $ \Gamma(l,k)$ prior.

So I know I need to find

$E[\lambda|X] = \lambda *\Pi(\lambda|X) d\lambda)$

I believe that $\Pi(\lambda|X) = (\Pi(\lambda))*F(X|\lambda))/m(x))$

And $f(x|\lambda)= \frac{(\lambda)^r}{\Gamma(r)}*x^{r-1}*e^{-\lambda*x} $ and $\Pi(\lambda)= \frac{\lambda^{L-1}*k^L*e^{-k\lambda}}{\Gamma(L)}$

I then tried to plug this back into the above formula hoping I would get some conjugate prior but with little to no luck. I'm still not convinced my setup is right as well however and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X_i|\Lambda=\lambda \sim \Gamma(r,\lambda)$ and $\Lambda \sim \Gamma(l,k)$ where $l,k,$ and $r$ are constant. Notice how $$\begin{eqnarray*}f(x_1,...,x_n|\lambda)f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)&=&\frac{\lambda^r}{\Gamma(r)}x_1^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x_1}\times \dots \times \frac{\lambda^r}{\Gamma(r)}x_n^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x_n} \times \frac{k^l}{\Gamma(l)}\lambda^{l-1}e^{-kl} \\ &=& \frac{(x_1 \dots x_n)^{r-1}k^l \lambda ^{nr+l-1}e^{-\lambda(x_1+\dots +x_n+k)}}{\big(\Gamma(r)\big)^n \Gamma (l)}\end{eqnarray*}$$ Using $\int_0^{\infty}t^ae^{-bt}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{b^{a+1}}$ we get $$\int_0^{\infty}f(x_1,...,x_n|\lambda)f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\lambda=\frac{(x_1...x_n)^{r-1}k^l \Gamma (nr+l)}{\big(\Gamma(r)\big)^n \Gamma(l) (x_1 + \dots +x_n +k)^{nr+l}}$$

Dividing these two expressions yields our posterior distribution for $\lambda$. $$\begin{eqnarray*}f(\lambda|x_1,...,x_n) &=& \frac{f(x_1,...,x_n|\lambda)f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)}{\int_{0}^\infty f(x_1,...,x_n|\lambda)f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\lambda} \\ &=& \frac{(x_1 + \dots + x_n +k)^{nr+l}}{\Gamma(nr+l)}\lambda^{nr+l-1}e^{-\lambda(x_1 + \dots + x_n + k)}\end{eqnarray*}$$ This shows $$\Lambda|X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n \sim \Gamma(nr+l,x_1+\dots +x_n+k)$$ Hence our posterior mean is $\frac{nr+l}{x_1 + \dots + x_n +k}$.